# How to fix "cy.find() failed because this element is detached from the DOM" in a loop?

Tags: cypress

I have a table and I need to fill in each cell.

First, I am getting the first row and with find() method each cell.

But the issue am I having is that the element is somehow getting detached from the DOM:

***cy.find() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.
The previous command that ran was:
cy.wrap()***

This is my code:

```
cy.get('.ag-center-cols-container .ag-row').each(($el, index, $list) => {
     cy.wrap($el).find('div[col-id="account"]').type("30000")
 })
```

I tried different approaches but did not find the solution to it.

For example:

cy.get('#row').each(($el, index, $list) => {

```
  cy.wrap($el).should($el => {
    expect(Cypress.dom.isAttached($el), 'is attached').to.eq(true)
  })
  .find('div[col-id="account"]').type("30000")
```

})

has the error:

***Timed out retrying after 10000ms: is attached: expected false to equal true***

I am new to Cypress and as far as I understand, I need to use **cy.wrap()** in this situation, in order to be able to use Cypress commands on the element.

I have 2 rows in this table and I was trying to use each just to make a reusable function in case I want to add more rows with data later in time.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: may help https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5743

Comment: You can't use `type()` on a `div`, see https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Supported-Elements.  You need to get the `input` or any element supported with `type()`. It might also solve your `DOM detached` problem.

Comment: Please add your html to the question.

Comment: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/detached/

Comment: @PeaceAndQuiet I changed my code to : cy.get('.ag-center-cols-container .ag-row').each(($el, index, $list) => {
      cy.wrap($el).find('div[col-id="account"] div input').type("30000") })                                    and I still get the detached from DOM error.

Comment: @Jonbonjovi this is a great video, I went through it but didn't see any new link loaded in my app  :(

Comment: @AlapanDas  I added the html

Answer (score 0):

Since all your `#row` get packaged in jquery elements at the `get()` command, some page refreshing code must happen in the background that makes these jquery elements detached when you try to recycle them in your `wrap()` to get your cell.
I once tried to re `get()` the elements inside the loop and it worked for me.

```js
cy.get('#row').each(($el, index, $list) => {
    cy.get('#row').eq(index).find('div[col-id="account"] input').type('30000');
});
```

Comment: I tried this and now I get:       Timed out retrying after 10000ms: cy.type() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.

<input aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="a335e7aa3a31">
Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.
The previous command that ran was:
  > cy.find()                              I also noticed that if I add a time out before the cy.get('#row').each.....    as in cy.wait(2000) it works ok, but this is against best practices

Comment: FYI cy.wait is not bad solution watch the video from Bahmutov he also use wait
glebbahmutov.com/blog/detached

Comment: @Jon-bon-jovi is right. Sometimes, the best solution is to lose 2 seconds on a working test execution rather than loose a lot more time trying to figure out how to sync properly. I don't like `cy.wait()` but I do have to use it sometimes.

Comment: Ok, I get this, but the issue would be that I have to fill in around 24 cells / row, so cy.wait(500) (which works fine) before each one is a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try:

1. Using a `visible` assertion with a timeout:

```js
cy.get('.ag-center-cols-container.ag-row')
  .should('be.visible')
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    cy.wrap($el)
      .find('div[col-id="account"]')
      .should('be.visible', {timeout: 6000})
      .type('30000')
  })
```

2. Typing with `{force: true}`:

```js
cy.get('.ag-center-cols-container.ag-row')
  .should('be.visible')
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    cy.wrap($el)
      .find('div[col-id="account"]')
      .should('be.visible', {timeout: 6000})
      .type('30000', {force: true})
  })
```